# Spring MVC with Atmosphere

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, atmosphere

I have recently started with Atmosphere. I need it to implement it in a Spring MVC application.

Till now I've managed to integrate it with Spring MVC.

I just need to perform a very simple task. I have a counter an instance variable as soon as it reaches 10, a response should be broadcasted to the UI.

Can anyone help me how do I write the code for that in the controller.

I've got the Atmosphere resource into the controller.

AtmosphereArgumentResolver.java

```
public class AtmosphereArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    //@Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return AtmosphereResource.class.isAssignableFrom(parameter.getParameterType());
    }

    //@Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception
    {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest= webRequest.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
        return Meteor.build(httpServletRequest).getAtmosphereResource();
    }
}
```

HomeController.java

```
  @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        private int counter = 0;

        private final BroadcasterFactory bf;


    public BroadcasterFactory broadcasterFactory()
    {
        return BroadcasterFactory.getDefault();
    }

        for(int i=0; i<=15; i++)
    {
       counter ++;
    }

    // As soon as the counter reaches 10 I need to send a broadcast message to the UI.



}
```

Can anyone please help? A skeleton code would also help as in which Atmosphere method to use for this?

Answer (score 0):

I will copy/past the code i use in my application :

Controller :

```
@ManagedService(path = "/websocket/*")
@Singleton
public class LanesWebSocket {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LanesWebSocket.class);

//  private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

    private Future<?> scheduleFixedBroadcast;

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private SupervisionCenterService supervisionCenterService;


    @Ready
    public void onReady(final AtmosphereResource resource) {

        if (this.supervisionCenterService == null)
            supervisionCenterService = SpringApplicationContext.getBean(SupervisionCenterService.class);

        Broadcaster bc = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup("lanes",true);

        bc.addAtmosphereResource(resource);

            scheduleFixedBroadcast = bc.scheduleFixedBroadcast(new Callable<String>() {

                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    try {
                        return mapper.writeValueAsString(supervisionCenterService.findCenterData());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        scheduleFixedBroadcast.cancel(true);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
```

And you also need to register the atmosphere servlet :

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

[...]

    @Override
        protected void registerDispatcherServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
            super.registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);
            initAtmosphereServlet(servletContext);
        }

        private void initAtmosphereServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
            AtmosphereServlet servlet = new AtmosphereServlet();
            Field frameworkField = ReflectionUtils.findField(AtmosphereServlet.class, "framework");
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(frameworkField);
            ReflectionUtils.setField(frameworkField, servlet, new NoAnalyticsAtmosphereFramework());
            ServletRegistration.Dynamic atmosphereServlet =
                    servletContext.addServlet("atmosphereServlet", servlet);

            atmosphereServlet.setInitParameter("org.atmosphere.cpr.packages", "com.myclient.theproduct.supervision.websocket");
            atmosphereServlet.setInitParameter("org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass", UUIDBroadcasterCache.class.getName());
            atmosphereServlet.setInitParameter("org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.shareableThreadPool", "true");
            atmosphereServlet.setInitParameter("org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxProcessingThreads", "10");
            atmosphereServlet.setInitParameter("org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxAsyncWriteThreads", "10");
            servletContext.addListener(new org.atmosphere.cpr.SessionSupport());

            atmosphereServlet.addMapping("/websocket/*");
            atmosphereServlet.setLoadOnStartup(3);
            atmosphereServlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
        }

    public class NoAnalyticsAtmosphereFramework extends AtmosphereFramework {

        public NoAnalyticsAtmosphereFramework() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void analytics() {
            // nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Don't ask me the reason of the `NoAnalyticsAtmosphereFramework` class, it could not work without.

Hope this will help you !

Comment: When the client connects to the websocket servlet, my controller send data each sec throught a Task